# How do you add a non-program-files application to the OpenWith dialog box?

Tags: windows-7, windows

In Windows 7, how can you add a non-"program files" application to the "Open With" options?

i.e.  For instance, when I try to ...  and browse the the path:

```
C:\MyApp\MyAppProg.exe
```

It doesn't show up in the "Open With">"Other Programs" section?...

Note:  a different app shows up under the "Open With">"Recommended Programs" section, but it is not the program I want.

Comment: i couldn't understand what you mean. you want to open a file with a program (or file) which is not listed in "Open with" dialog?

Comment: Have you tried [OpenWithView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/open_with_view.html)? It won't associate a file extension with a program but it should help you to get a program into your "open with" list.

Comment: After you click OK to select the program, and browse in the dialog that appears, be sure to change the files of type to All Files. Doing so will allow you to navigate to any folder and pick the application you want.

Comment: @Armin - yes, "Open With">[Browse]>{Select MyAppProg.exe} >?> then it does not show up in the "Open With">"Other Programs" section in order to select.

Comment: @JC2k8 Ideally I'd like to not use an external program...  if I can't solve it otherwise, then I'll try it.

Comment: @martineau no effect...  either way I see the MyAppProg.exe file, & I select it; but when I click [Open], it doesn't show under the "Open With">"Other Programs" section in order to select.

Comment: Maybe you could use the [Right Click Enhancer](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/add-custom-shortcuts-system-paths-to-windows-context-menu/) and add your application to the right-click Send To context menu instead.

Comment: yes it is possible by tweaking the `Windows Registry`. which extension *(.xyz file)* do you want to associate?

Comment: You should be able to use [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/718451/95106) to add to or set your own file association preferences including "Open with" dialog visibility. Whether it be manually or by coding it into your application.

Answer (score 1):

> **WARNING:** If you use Registry Editor incorrectly, you may cause serious problems that may require you to reinstall your operating system. Use Registry Editor at your own risk.

#### Add to "Recommended Programs" section of the Open With dialog

> **NOTE:** In Windows 7 this will also show on the "Open with" context menu for registered file types (see image below).

[image]

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts
```

Find or add a subkey of your chosen extension i.e ".bin", add or select subkey "OpenWithList" and add a `REG_SZ` value with a name `a` to `z` depending on existing entries just use the next available letter and set the value to the name of your application executable. This may mean having an entry already available in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications` that matches your executable name (see Add to "Other Programs" section of the Open With dialog section below).

You can control the order they appear by modifying the `MRUList` `REG_SZ` that will exist in the same subkey (see other extensions if you are unsure for how this is displayed).

You can also use subkey `OpenWithProgids` instead but this works differently and relies on you having a registered ProgId in the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` hive of the registry.

Here is an example exported from my `.asp` subkey

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.asp\OpenWithList]
"a"="PSPad.exe"
"MRUList"="bca"
"b"="NOTEPAD.EXE"
"c"="WinMergeU.exe"
```

#### Add to "Other Programs" section of the Open With dialog

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications
```

Create a Key called your executable for example "myapp.exe" using this as an example create the following structure (taken from a registry export .reg file);

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\myapp.exe\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\myapp.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the "Other Programs" section is intended to hold the names of other programs which have registered themselves as openers of the filetype concerned. When I use the
"browse" dialog, it works as expected, and the file opens in the program I select (or I get an
error msg if the program is inappropriate (using Win Vista here).

You can always just put a shortcut to your app in your SendTo folder. Then you can send
any file type you want to the app from the context menu.