# Edited registry keys keep reverting back to their original values

Tags: windows, windows-vista, windows-registry

OS: Windows Vista Home Premium SP2

I'm making the following changes so the program names in question are more user friendly in the 'open with' and 'programs' lists:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache]
"C:\\Program Files\\K-Lite Codec Pack\\Media Player Classic\\mpc-hc.exe"="Media Player Classic Home Cinema"
"C:\\Program Files\\MKVToolNix\\mmg.exe"="MKV Merge"
```

Every other week or so they revert back to "MPC-HC" and "mmg.exe" respectively! Why is that?

Comment: You're not supposed to manually edit the content of that registry key at all. In fact, it's used as a cache for localized strings, and as soon as it gets refreshed all changes are gone - just what you're experiencing. Consider editing the description of both executables instead, e.g. using [ResHacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) (make sure to create a backup of the original files first).

Comment: @and31415 Yes, but what is prompting this refresh? I had already experimented with such changes on Windows 7 and they seem to have stuck. I would've preferred avoiding "hardcoding" the changes, but might end up doing it if all registry hacks fail..

Comment: Increasing the mui cache size would probably help, but can it be done?

Comment: Now that I think about it, you might want to try setting the `FriendlyAppName` registry value, as explained here: [Application Registration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Well, I had already tried the FriendlyAppName approach with no effect. The way I went about it was by mimicking other existing registry entries and placing the "FriendlyAppName"/"Value" pair in the root of the application subkey. After further research, and although MS seem to advocate this usage through literature and practice, it seems the right way to do it is by adding the "FriendlyAppName"/"Value" pair to the application's default verb subkey (i.e. "open"), as suggested in the comments [here](http://goo.gl/4AcgZv) and [here](http://goo.gl/1jUWOM), and which does actually work.

Comment: Yes, I reached the same conclusions while [commenting on a related question](http://superuser.com/questions/789706/can-i-set-an-icon-for-for-an-application-registered-under-openwith?noredirect=1#comment1035324_789706). The official documentation is not up-to-date. The `FriendlyAppName` *was* meant to be in stored the root key, but that's no longer the case as of Windows XP. If the approach is fine with you, I might provide an actual answer :)

Comment: By all means, do provide an answer! :)

P.S. Microsoft still use `FriendlyAppName` in the applications' root key for some of their Windows tools (Calendar i.e. wincal.exe, Windows Media Player i.e. wmplayer.exe, etc..). There's still more to this, it seems...

Comment: On a separate note, I'm intrigued to why the `MuiCache` changes seem to have stuck for years on my Windows 7 machine.. Maybe a larger cache limit, or a different "refreshing" algorithm?

Comment: Well, apparently whoever put those registry values in the root key was probably following the official documentation. Here's a working example: [before](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5iNci.png) / [after](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wPSSp.png). As you can see, the value stored in the root key is *completely* ignored. This can also be confirmed by using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). As for the cache, the behavior might have changed slightly in Windows 7 but I don't know for sure. Either way, the `FriendlyAppName` value works fine there, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

You're not supposed to manually edit the content of the `MuiCache` registry key at all. Whenever the cache gets refreshed, the descriptions are read again from the related executable files, and your changes are reverted back.

Aside from patching the description using e.g. [ResHacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/), there's a built-in feature which can be useful in this case:

> You can also include a `FriendlyAppName` value to provide the system with a friendly name for your application. The application's friendly name may also be extracted from its executable file, but only if the `FriendlyAppName` value is absent.
>
> <sub>Source: [Extending Shortcut Menus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#anyfiletype)</sub>

1. Log on with an administrator account.
2. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type or paste `regedit.exe` in the text box, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Navigate to the following registry key:

   ```
   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications
   ```
4. Locate the subkey related to the application you're interested in. In case the application key is missing, follow these steps:

   a. Right-click the `Applications` key, and choose **New > Key** from the context menu.

   b. Name the key after the executable name (e.g. `whatever.exe`).

   c. Right-click the new key, and create a `shell` subkey. Create an `open` subkey inside the `shell` subkey.

   d. Create a subkey called `command` inside the `open` subkey. Double-click the `(Default)` value and set it to the path of the executable, plus `"%1"` to account the parameter to pass to the program. For example:

   ```
   "C:\Program Files\Whatever, Inc.\whatever.exe" "%1"
   ```
5. Navigate to the following key, where `whatever.exe` is the actual executable name:

   ```
   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\whatever.exe\shell\open
   ```
6. Right-click an empty area in the right pane, and choose **New > String Value** from the context menu. Name the new value `FriendlyAppName`, and set it as you like. Changes are applied immediately.

**Note** The official documentation is not up-to-date. The `FriendlyAppName` value *was* meant to be in stored the root application key, but that's no longer the case as of Windows XP.

### Additional information

> `FriendlyAppName`
>
> Provides a way to get a localizable name to display for an application instead of just the version information appearing, which may not be localizable. The association query [ASSOCSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762475(v=vs.85).aspx) reads this registry entry value and falls back to use the `FileDescription` name in the version information. If that name is missing, the association query defaults to the display name of the file.
>
> <sub>Source: [Application Registration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)</sub>

After starting a program, the descriptions is usually extracted from the executable file and stored in the following registry keys for later use:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\MuiCache
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache
```

Those registry keys are actually mapped to the user branch:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\MuiCache
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache
```

### Further reading

- [Application Registration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)